# How can I display VTT or other subtitle formats used by youtube-dl in VLC?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles, youtube-dl

For some reason, the subtitles don't work on VLC, is there something I need to be aware about, like converting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify which format doesn't work with vlc?

In my experiences, most of the time you don't need to convert the subtitles.

The result of this option `--write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang en,id --sub-format srt/best`

is like so: 
[image: result auto sub and specific languange]

Assuming the left side is the autosub, and the right side is the chosen language.
The subtitle from auto-sub is messy, but the other one is quite good.
That approach still can be adjusted, to give higher priority when downloading subtitle

`--write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang en,id --sub-format srt/sub/ssa/vtt/ass/best`

But if you want to make sure the subtitle is nicely displayed, see
another [option](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options) from youtube-dl:

- use `--embed-subs`
  , Embed subtitles in the video (only for mp4,
                               webm and mkv videos)
- use `--convert-subs FORMAT`
  , Convert the subtitles to other format
                               (currently supported: srt|ass|vtt|lrc)

You may want to take a look [supported format from vlc](https://www.vlchelp.com/load-external-subtitle/), surely you want to ask the format which supported from vlc and youtube-dl

Comment: wow, thanks, it worked... I'm curious of what I did wrong... what are the required option for it work? Maybe I omitted an argument?

Comment: perhaps it's the `--write-sub`, the `--write-auto-sub` is for automatic subtitle